# searching images on google to include into my app

Tags: android, android-image, web-search, webimage

I have a database full of item witout images. i'd like to show an image when the user watches the detail of an item. My idea was to search an image on google, take the first result and then include it in the activity.
Can this be done with android? and if so, what's the best (or maybe the easyest) practice?

Comment: I think you will get Copyright Problems, if this is working

Comment: this is not a problem, it's an application for private uses, i wont put it on the store..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview to search images

Comment: That plugin was created for web-programs, not for android, so i think it's not the solution to my problem. I've tried to include the code given to me by google(from that site) using a webview, but it's no use, it always crash...